# sending email with the click of a button with data from different page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an admin page that collects the data from a form user submitted in the form of a table. I want to have a button that recognize the user email column when clicked and send them a premade email.

Of course I've looked around, but all of the ones with similar problem as me have it, so their form is also in the same page as the button, so they can do `$_POST` and `mailto`. I can't do that because the form is in different page.

This is the table where admin sees user info:

```
<td><?php echo $v['telephone']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $v['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $v['website']; ?></td>
```

and then this is the button an admin would press to send it:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send confirmation" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
```

and under it is the php code to send it:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
$to      = $v['email'];
$subject = 'ayayay';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Nothing seems to happen when I click it. Of course I don't actually get the email either. What am I missing here?

I have header tag up above either, not sure if it actually does anything for this page but I looked around and they said it might help but it didn't.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

Comment: *"nothing seems to happen when i click it"* - It's a submit button, but where's the form?  What are you "submitting" when you click that button?

Comment: Are you seeing any warnings/errors in the logs? Have you set up a mail server?

Comment: @David the form is in different page. this page is table filled with info from that form

Comment: @ficuscr no error. and i think so. otherwise the stuff from the form wouldnt arrive to this page at all, right?

Answer (score 2):

> the form is in different page

But you're still trying to submit a form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send confirmation" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
```

Regardless of what form may exist on another page, in order to submit *this* form you still need a form here.  For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="Send confirmation" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>
```

Add whatever URL you may need for the `action` if not the current page's URL.  And of course any `input` elements you may need for additional values.  For example, if you need an input with the `$v['email']` value then you'd add one:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="Send confirmation" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $v['email']; ?>" />
</form>
```

Then in your form handler for this, where you send the email, you'd use `$_POST['email']` like with any other form.  For example:

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
```